# TFS API get work item data

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

i m stuck on simple problem with TFS API, when im getting work item, i cant get workitem Effort data, the idea is to get work item form the TFS by specific criteria, and then change Effort data and save it back to the TFS. Now i can get work item, and update any data by field, but i din;t found how to get Effort, and update it.

[image]

Query for getting data from TFS:

```
SELECT * FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.WorkItemType] = 'Task' AND [Assigned to] = 'name' 
ORDER BY [System.WorkItemType], [System.Id]
```

And this is the code to fetch the fields

```
public void getDataFromTfs()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Getting data from TFS to Store");
    Console.WriteLine("*********************");
    setQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("Query" + byTasksModified.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("*********************");
    Console.ReadLine();
    credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxx", "xxxxxx", "xxxxx");
    TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection =
    new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(@"LINK HERE"), credentials);
    teamProjectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();
    Store = (WorkItemStore) teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
    WIC = Store.Query(byTasksAssignedTo);
    Console.WriteLine("Data fetched into Store");
    foreach (WorkItem workItem in WIC)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", workItem.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", workItem.Title);
    }
}
```

Here I'm getting all tasks that i need by specific query, and then i have method to pull specific task

```
public void getSpecificWorkItemData()
{
    workItem = Store.GetWorkItem(64);
    Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", workItem.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", workItem.Title);

    workItem.Open();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

and then i have update method for the task

```
public void updateWorkItem()
{
   workItem.Fields["Assigned to"].Value = "NAME";

   if (workItem.IsValid() == false)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Item is not valid");
   }
   else
   {
        try
        {
            workItem.Save();
        }
        catch (ValidationException exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error saving work item!");
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Item Saved");
        workItem.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the thing that doesn't work. What id it that you exactly what you want to do?

Comment: Well when i pull the work item, work item dont have any information about Effort, and i need to pull Effort data too, so i can change it and then update it in TFS. As I understand there is no way i can change effort data using WorkItem.Fields[]

Comment: So, That means that in my query where im pulling all items i have [System.WorkItemType] = 'Task', I should change it to Product Backlog Item, and then I will be able to change the Effort using fields?

Comment: Still Thats strange, because i have Taks, that got Effort data, http://i.imgur.com/YpMuRCD.png, and when im using my query i see this task in the WorkItemColletion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on your process template which fields are available. Right now you're querying on "Task" work items, which has the following fields in the "Effort" group by default. Note that there is no "Effort" field for tasks, there are these other:

```
Process Template    | Field (s)
Scrum               | Remaining Work
MSF Agile           | Remaining Work, Completed Work, Original estimate
MSF CMMI            | Remaining Work, Completed Work, Original estimate
```

The Effort field you're after is defined in the Scrum process template and is used by all work items in the Requirement Category (Product Backlog Item and Bug by default):

```
Process Template    | Field (s)
Scrum               | Effort
MSF Agile           | Story Point
MSF CMMI            | Size
```

If you want to update the Effort field in the work items in the Scrum Process template, it's best to query work items that are in the Work Item Type Category "Requirement Category":

```
SELECT * 
    FROM WorkItems 
    WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @project  
        AND  [System.WorkItemType] IN GROUP 'Requirement Category'  
    ORDER BY [System.Id]
```

If you want to update the Remaining work, Completed Work or Original Estimate fields, you need to use the Tasks:

```
SELECT id, Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork, Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork, Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate
    FROM WorkItems 
    WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @project  
        AND  [System.WorkItemType] IN GROUP 'Task Category'  
    ORDER BY [System.Id]
```

And then update them based on their Ref name, as defined in the [TFS Field Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997792.aspx), is the safest way to go:

```
workItem.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork"].Value = 123;
workItem.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork"].Value = 123;
workItem.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate"].Value = 123;
```

Comment: Okay, but how to update that Effort fields? Didn't found that information. :) Thanks in advice. Because I've didnt found any inforamtion how i can update it using WorkItem.Field[] method. Same for showing that Effort data.

Comment: OH, Thanks a lot for your answer Jesse! You helped me a lot :)